# Calling Values from a .properties file?

Tags: bash, scripts

Right now I have a simple script I want to now call a .properties file and then print the results of that file, this is what I have so far

```
#Specific Set Variables 
SpecficStatus="Pass" #SetVariable 
timestamp() { date +"%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"; }
SpecficDate=$(timestamp)

echo $SpecficStatus
echo $SpecficDate

#Properties Call
file="savedState.properties"

#Echo out the file

while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < savedState.properties
```

Whats in my savedState.properties file

```
WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP=Wed 20 May 2015 13:50:51 UTC
WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS=false
WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP=Wed 20 May 2015 13:50:51 UTC
WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS=false
```

As you can see from the script I can call the file and print out the results but What I want is to be able to choose which values and store them as variables for later use in the script ??

Any help would be great

Comment: Could you paste the content of your savedState.properties file? It would help understand your ask better.

Comment: @rahul I have updated the question with what you asked

Comment: Thanks. So you would like to choose only the MANAGEGOLD or MANAGERC related lines and save them as variables to be used later?

Comment: well i was hoping to store all 4 as different variables so i would like to call each one on its own for example WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export them like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Specific Set Variables 
SpecficStatus="Pass" #SetVariable 
timestamp() { date +"%a %d %b %Y %T %Z"; }
SpecficDate=$(timestamp)

echo $SpecficStatus
echo $SpecficDate

#Properties Call
file="savedState.properties"
#Echo out the file


while IFS== read -r VAR1 VAR2
do
    #echo "VAR1=$VAR1 : VAR2=$VAR2"
    export "$VAR1=$VAR2"
done < savedState.properties

echo "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP"
echo "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS"
echo "$WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP"
echo "$WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS"
```

This prints out :

```
Pass
Wed 20 May 2015 12:24:26 EDT
Wed 20 May 2015 13:50:51 UTC
false
Wed 20 May 2015 13:50:51 UTC
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`, to store e.g. `WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP`'s value into a `wd_managegold_datetimestamp` variable and `WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS`'s value into a `wd_managegold_success` variable:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# ...
wd_managegold_datetimestamp=$(< savedState.properties grep -Po '^WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP=\K.*')
wd_managegold_success=$(< savedState.properties grep -Po '^WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS=\K.*')
# ...
```

But in this case it might be convenient to store related values into an array, so to store e.g. all `WD_MANAGEGOLD` and `WD_MANAGERC` values into two `wd_managegold` and `wd_managerc` arrays:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# ...
IFS=$'\n\r' GLOBIGNORE='*' wd_managegold=($(< savedState.properties grep -Po '^WD_MANAGEGOLD_.*=\K.*'))
IFS=$'\n\r' GLOBIGNORE='*' wd_managerc=($(< savedState.properties grep -Po '^WD_MANAGERC_.*=\K.*'))
# ...
```

- `IFS=$'\n\r'`: Sets `bash`'s internal field separator to both the newline character and the carriage return character, so that every newline / carriage return separated value gets stored into a single array's field;
- `GLOBIGNORE='*'`: Sets `bash`'s builtin `GLOBIGNORE` variable to `*`, so that values matching special filenames won't be treated specially